# How I should access the values of a model data using serilog

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

The situation is the following :

I have an endpoint X of a controller which receives a model data parameter Person.cs with attribute string Name for example.

This parameter will be populated Name = "John"

using serilog, I have the data like method type, endpoint name, and others, but I don't know how to access the value "John".
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Andrei Fulea Please describe your question better so we can help you.